# Continuing a line with a new line in tikz using the slope equation isn't working as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, diagrams, line

I have the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1, 1);
\coordinate (B) at (2, 2);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] let \p1 = (A), \p2 = (B) in (B) -- (5, {((\y2-\y1)/(\x2-\x1))*(5-\x1) + \y1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

One knows that the line equation can be calculated with

y-y0 = m(x-x0)

where the slope m = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0).

Here, you can see that x = 5 in my case but the new line doesn't follow the original line as expected. Instead I get the following:

[image]

However when choosing x = 0 it works somehow. I'm lost on why it isn't working like expected for the other points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a coordinate is evaluated PGF/TikZ only knows its position in the [**`canvas`** coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas) (**with** units). The [**`xyz`** coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz) just transform your *x*, *y* and *z* values (**without** units) into the `canvas` coordinate system. (By default, for *x* and *y* this means just multiplication with `1cm`.)

The `\x` and `\y` shorthands only return values in the `canvas` coordinate system and indeed letting TeX write

```
((\y2-\y1)/(\x2-\x1))*(5-\x1) + \y1
```

on the page or the log file will result in

```
((56.90549pt-28.45274pt)/(56.90549pt–28.45274pt))*(5–28.45274pt) + 28.45274pt
```

The lonely `5` will now be interpreted as `5pt` and not `5` (or `5cm`).

---

One solution would be to parse `(5, <any y value>)` in `\p3` and use `\x3` instead of `5` or you can use the undocumented [`intersection of` coordinate specification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659568/16595) and just let TikZ to the math for you, i.e. find the point where the line through `A` and `B` meets the vertical line through *x* = 5.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1, 1);
\coordinate (B) at (2, 2);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] let \p1 = (A),
                  \p2 = (B),
                  \p3 = (5,0) in
  (B) -- (5, {((\y2-\y1)/(\x2-\x1))*(\x3-\x1) + \y1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1, 1);
\coordinate (B) at (2, 2);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (intersection of A--B and 5,0--5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, you can also use `-1`, `1`, `2` and `2` inside PGFMath but then you will need to have your own macros/functions for those and make the coordinate specification dependent on those values, too.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzcoors(-1,1)(A)(2,2)(B);
\tzLFn(A)(B)[-1:5]<edge[dashed,blue] ([turn]0:5cm)> % to extend
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, you can also:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzcoors(-1,1)(A)(2,2)(B);
\tzLFn(A)(B)[-1:5]
\tzpointangle(A)(B){\angleAB} % calculate the angle
\tzLFn[dashed](B){tan(\angleAB)}[5:10]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```