# Default unit for x,y components of `tikzmath` coordinate is in `pt`

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, units, tikzmath

Lets say I want to draw a line on a grid given two points A,B:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%mixing defs and coordinates is a bad idea  
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,calc,matrix,math,positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\xmax{7}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (\xmax,\xmax);
\tikzmath{
coordinate \A, \B; 
\A =(1,2);
\B =(4,4);
}
\draw[fill=black] (\A) circle [radius=1pt] node[above,xshift=-1pt] {$A$};
\draw[fill=black] (\B) circle [radius=1pt] node[above,xshift=-1pt] {$B$};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gradient}{(\By-\Ay)/(\Bx-\Ax)};
\draw (0,\Ay-\gradient*\Ax) -- (\xmax,\Ay-\gradient*\Ax+\gradient*\xmax);
\draw[fill=green] (0,\Ay-\gradient*\Ax) circle [radius=1pt] ;
\draw[fill=red] (\xmax,\Ay-\gradient*\Ax+\gradient*\xmax) circle [radius=1pt] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates,

[image: ![enter image description here]

which produces a correct left boundary (green dot) but an incorrect right boundary (red dot). It turns out that `\Ax` and `\Ay` are not equal to 1cm and 2cm but instead are expressed in pts and
are equal to 28.45274 and 56.90549. Because `\gradient` is calculated using these units
and the expression for the green dot also uses these units I get the correct result. This is not the case for the red dot since `\xmax` is definitely not in pts. The result is a y coordinate equal to 42.60365 pt or 1.497348 cm.

Is there a way to avoid this unit mess by forcing the coordinates defined in `tikzmath` to use the default unit of cm?

Comment: Basically the same problem as [Q687376](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/687376). No, once input, coordinates are always in the canvas coordinate system. The *xyz* coordinate system is only used for a one-way transformation into the canvas coordinate system. The values are then lost. (There might be TikZ addons or a future update of TikZ that changes this. I believe one 3d TikZ expansion might do this internally.) What are you trying to do? There are easier ways to find points on a line through two points or parallel to it with TikZ that don't need you do to math.

Comment: Of course, you can always save `\Ax` to be `1`, `\Ay` to be `2` and then use `(\Ax,\Ay)` instead of `\A` (or even define `\A` to be `\Ax, \Ay`) which would allow you to use the `\Ax` and `\Ay` macros as you wish.

Comment: The green dot can be found by `(intersection of 0,0--0,1 and A--B)` which the red one can be found by `(intersection of 5,0--5,1 and A--B)` (where `x,0--x,1` just describes a vertical line with *x* value `x`), this basically does the same math for you.

Comment: In this case, you could simply replace `\Ay-\gradient*\Ax+\gradient*\xmax` by `\Ay-\gradient*\Ax+\gradient*\xmax*1cm` and this way clarify that you mean 7cm and not 7pt.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel I was aware of the `intersection` method. Its good that I have confirmed that it is the default behavior and that there is no way to change the default units of the canvas coordinate system.